# Is there a way to enable the media keys when the screen is locked?

Tags: 10.10, sound, laptop

I own a [Dell Studio XPS 16](http://www.dell.com/us/p/studio-xps-1647/pd).

The media keys work fine when logged in, but stop working after the screen is locked. Although I can imagine this being classified under the 'feature, not a bug' class, in some cases it could still be a very handy option to be able to to mute the sound when the screen is locked, for example.

***Is there a way to use the media keys, even when the screen is locked?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem and reason it's not possible is because it's considered a bit of a security problem if the locked computer can communicate with the desktop.

Might be worth a gnome bug report though.

Not currently possible.

Comment: Just found this because I had the same question. Is there any change on the topic since it's been two years?